# Only show instances that equal the max value in temp table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a new table with only the `sname`'s that equal the maximum number of `num_courses` which is a column in a temporary table `n`.

```
SELECT s.sname, n.num_courses
FROM (SELECT e.sid, COUNT(distinct e.cno) as num_courses
      FROM enroll e
      GROUP BY e.sid) n, student s
WHERE s.sid = n.sid AND n.num_courses = (SELECT MAX(n.num_course) from n) x;
```

Is it possible to only show instances that equal the max value found in a temporary table? (Referring to the second `WHERE` clause on the last line)

This is the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1 in file: 'q7.sql': You have an error in your
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near 'x' at line 5
```

It says the error is at line 1 but when I remove the last clause on the last line, there's no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reuse the subquery like that. You'll need to write the query again in the where clause.

I think you intended to do this:

```
select s.sname,
    n.num_courses
from (
    select e.sid,
        COUNT(distinct e.cno) as num_courses
    from enroll e
    group by e.sid
    ) n,
    student s
where s.sid = n.sid
    and n.num_courses = (
        select MAX(n.num_course)
        from (
            select COUNT(distinct e.cno) as num_courses
            from enroll e
            group by e.sid
            ) t
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need x tablename and you can't use the n table alias but you need  all the code

```
  SELECT s.sname, n.num_courses
  FROM (SELECT e.sid, COUNT(distinct e.cno) as num_courses
        FROM enroll e
        GROUP BY e.sid) n 
  INNER JOIN  student s ON s.sid = n.sid AND  (SELECT MAX(n.num_course) from 
  ( SELECT e.sid, COUNT(distinct e.cno) as num_courses
        FROM enroll e
        GROUP BY e.sid) n )
```

Comment: Exactly what I answered.

Comment: I use a more properly  ..  join format  .. but  the problem is the same

Comment: @GurV  and you have myupvote  for .. a fast and correct answer .. many thanks

Comment: Thanks for helping me figure out what I needed to do +1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that alias in `WHERE` condition and also try using `IN` instead since `MAX()` could return multiple result like

```
n.num_courses IN (SELECT MAX(n.num_course) from n);
```

Comment: There is no group by clause. So max will **never** return multiple rows here.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. Still gives me an error.